# How to override hibernate JPA filter on inherited class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am using hibernate JPA.

I have a `BasePersonnel` class as super class that has a `filter`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_PERSONEL")
@Filters({
    @Filter(name = "authorize", 
            condition = " 1 = 1 ")
})
public class BasePersonel extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    ...
}
```

and it has a child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RTS_PERSONNEL")
@Filters({
    @Filter(name = "authorize",
            condition = " 2 = 2 ")
})
public class Personnel extends BasePersonel {
    ...
}
```

When I run query on `Personnel` class using hql, both filters(ie super class's filter and child class's filter) append to `where` clause.
But I want just child class filter append to `where` clause.

Is there any solution to override super class filter?

Comment: How is your query performed?  Using JPA query methods? Or explicitly through the session?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`@Subselect`](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-jpa-entity-to-view-or-sql-query-with-hibernate/) when mapping the entity.

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from APP_PERSONEL where authorize = 1")
public class BasePersonel extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wish `@Where` worked on super-entities, but this suggestion fixes it.